# ¿Como puedo ejecutar un PATCH para un datastore en django de python?

Tags: python, django, postman, google-datastore

Eso pues, quiero hacer un PATCH desde postman para actualizar unos datos a un datastore que tengo y no se me ocurren mas ideas que esta:

```
@csrf_exempt
    def patch(request, id):
        JSON = json.loads(request.body)
        confirmation = []
        lists = list(JSON.keys())
        words = ['longitude','latitude','sensors','object_id','station_id','timestamp']
        datastoreAPI = DatastoreAPI()
        datastore = datastoreAPI.get(request) #sacar el json del datastore
        print(datastore)
        if "'id' : {id}" in datastore:
            verif = True
            for i in range(len(lists)):
                verif2=False
                for j in range(len(words)):
                    if lists[i] == words[j]:
                        verif2 = True
                        break
                confirmation.append(verif2)
            for k in range(len(confirmation)):
                if not confirmation[k]:
                    verif = False
                    break
            if (verif):
                dataStoreConnector = DatastoreConnector()
                res = dataStoreConnector.patch_JSON(JSON, id)
                return JsonResponse(res)
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'msg' : f"Error de campos: uno o varios campos están mal escritos o son incorrectos"})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'msg': f"Id no encontrada"})
```

Esos `if()` son para corroborar que los argumentos son correctos y/o que estén bien escritos

Del `datastoreAPI.get()` esta asi (este metodo no lo quiero cambiar porque lo estoy usando en otra cosa):

```
def get(self, request):
        type = request.GET['type'] if 'type' in request.GET else None
        stationId = request.GET['stationid'] if 'stationid' in request.GET else None
        sensorId = request.GET['sensorid'] if 'sensorid' in request.GET else None
        now = datetime.now()
        firstTime = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 0, 0, 00, 00000)
        startDate = datetime.timestamp(firstTime)
        endDate = datetime.timestamp(now)
        if 'startdate' in request.GET:
            startDate = request.GET['startdate']
        if 'enddate' in request.GET:
            endDate = request.GET['enddate']

        print(startDate)
        print(endDate)

        datastoreConnector = DatastoreConnector()
        data = datastoreConnector.read(
            stationId, sensorId, 
            'aquamype_sensordata', startDate, endDate)
        
        if type == 'csv':
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv; charset=utf-8')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="data.csv"'

            writer = csv.writer(response)
            writer.writerow([
                'stationId', 'stationName', 'sensorId', 
                'sensorName', 'value', 'timestamp'
            ])
            for d in data:
                writer.writerow([
                    d['stationId'], d['stationName'], d['sensorId'], 
                    d['sensorName'], d['value'], d['timestamp']
                ])
            return response
        else:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
                "data" : data,
                "msg": "OK"
            }), content_type="application/json")
```

Y en el `dataStoreConnector.patch_JSON()` tengo esto:

```
def patch_JSON(self, data, id):
        entity = datastore.Entity(
            key=self.datastoreClient.key('aquamype_sensordata'))
        entity.key.id
        entity.update(
            data
        )
        self.datastoreClient.patch(entity)
        return data
```

El problema es que ya que los datos de la datastore son bastantes, el GET se demora mucho en obtener los datos (eso creo que se puede optimizar), pero lo mas importante es que cuando busca los datos dice "id no encontrada", esto es lo que sale en el `print(datastore)`:

```
<HttpResponse status_code=200, "application/json">
```

Cuando deberia de salirme toda la informacion.

Tambien estoy viendo que si saliese toda la informacion saltaria error o no ejecutaria de la forma que ejecuta un PATCH

Comment: por que revertiste la edición?

Comment: Y, por que editaste mi publicacion?

Comment: Para rarrehkar algunas cosas